# TypeError: d3.geo is undefined in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js, geo

I am doing a project based on ruby on rails.I want to draw a world map in it and use the d3.js library .I put the all the needed library in /vendor/assets/javascript(jquery,d3,topojson,d3-geo,datamap.min)And I want to use a library based on d3:http://datamaps.github.io/.But there always the error in console said"TypeError: d3.geo is undefined".I googled much but still have no idea.Does anyone know about what is the problem in it?
Thanks so much.

Comment: as it says: some code doesn't know what d3.geo is..

Comment: if you are using d3v4 rather than v3, you may need to change your code if it is from a v3 map. For example, geo.path is now geoPath. See api documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#geographies-d3-geo

Comment: Datamaps is still stuck at D3 v3. Have a look at my answer to [*"Datamaps is giving me a Cannot read property 'albersUsa' of undefined"*](/q/40405692).

Comment: @altocumulus thanks~I changed it to d3.v3. It is resolved.